# Importing .scss from apps, breaks library build, Angular11

Tags: angular

I am using .scss from an application into the lib, i have set option in angular.json,

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
     "includePaths": ["projects/magic-string-example/src/app/styles", "node_modules/"]
 }
```

And in the library component, using like this

```
@import '_variables';
```

This is working during ng-serve, but when i try to build the lib I am getting error:

```
ERROR: Can't find stylesheet to import.
@import '_variables';
```

I trying to search on web, but so solution found yet, need some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add files in the angular.json within the stylePreprocessorOptions-property by updating your angular file in projects/projectName/architect/test and projects/projectName/architect/build with:

```
"options": {
    "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
      "includePaths": ["src/assets/styles"]
    }
}
```